# Scroll horizontally when dragging/reordering columns in the TableView

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

In JavaFX's `TableView` (and `TreeTableView`) it's really hard to reorder columns using drag & drop when the horizontal scrollbar is present, because the table doesn't scroll automatically when one want's to drag the column to the currently not visible (off the scroll pane viewport) position.

I've noticed that there are already a bug (enhancement) reports for this:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092314
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092355
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213739

... but as it haven't been tackled for quite some time I am wondering whether there is any other way to achieve the same behavior using the current API.

There is SSCCE:

```
public class TableViewColumnReorderDragSSCCE extends Application {

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 30;
    public static final int MAX_WINDOW_WIDTH = 480;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createTable()));
        stage.show();
        stage.setMaxWidth(MAX_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    }

    private TableView<List<String>> createTable() {
        final TableView<List<String>> tableView = new TableView<>();
        initColumns(tableView);
        return tableView;
    }

    private void initColumns(TableView<List<String>> tableView) {
        for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; i++) {
            tableView.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("Column " + i));
        }
        tableView.getItems().add(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the above SSCCE
2. Try to drag `Column 0` after `Column 29`

[image]

I am after a fully functional solution (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no complete solution was provided I've came up with one of my own. I've introduced a (`ColumnsOrderingEnhancer`) implementation which will enhance the table view columns reordering by automatic scrolling (when needed).

Usage (with the table view defined in the above SSCCE):

```
// Enhance table view columns reordering
final ColumnsOrderingEnhancer<List<String>> columnsOrderingEnhancer = new ColumnsOrderingEnhancer<>(tableView);
columnsOrderingEnhancer.init();
```

`ColumnsOrderingEnhancer` implementation:

```
public class ColumnsOrderingEnhancer<T> {

    private final TableView<T> tableView;

    public ColumnsOrderingEnhancer(TableView<T> tableView) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
    }

    public void init() {
        tableView.skinProperty().addListener((observable, oldSkin, newSkin) -> {

            // This can be done only when skin is ready
            final TableHeaderRow header = (TableHeaderRow) tableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
            final MouseDraggingDirectionHelper mouseDraggingDirectionHelper = new MouseDraggingDirectionHelper(header);
            final ScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = getTableViewHorizontalScrollbar();

            // This is the most important part which is responsible for scrolling table during the column dragging out of the viewport.
            header.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, event -> {
                final double totalHeaderWidth = header.getWidth();
                final double xMousePosition = event.getX();
                final MouseDraggingDirectionHelper.Direction direction = mouseDraggingDirectionHelper.getLastDirection();
                maybeChangeScrollBarPosition(horizontalScrollBar, totalHeaderWidth, xMousePosition, direction);
            });

        });
    }

    private void maybeChangeScrollBarPosition(ScrollBar horizontalScrollBar, double totalHeaderWidth, double xMousePosition, MouseDraggingDirectionHelper.Direction direction) {
        if (xMousePosition > totalHeaderWidth && direction == RIGHT) {
            horizontalScrollBar.increment();
        }
        else if (xMousePosition < 0 && direction == LEFT) {
            horizontalScrollBar.decrement();
        }
    }

    private ScrollBar getTableViewHorizontalScrollbar() {
        Set<Node> scrollBars = tableView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
        final Optional<Node> horizontalScrollBar =
                  scrollBars.stream().filter(node -> ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation().equals(Orientation.HORIZONTAL)).findAny();
        try {
            return (ScrollBar) horizontalScrollBar.get();
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple class responsible for determining horizontal direction of the mouse during dragging phase.
     */
    static class MouseDraggingDirectionHelper {

        private double xLastMousePosition = -1;
        private Direction direction = null;

        MouseDraggingDirectionHelper(Node node) {
            // Event filters that are determining when scrollbar needs to be incremented/decremented
            node.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> xLastMousePosition = event.getX());
            node.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, event -> {
                direction = ((event.getX() - xLastMousePosition > 0) ? RIGHT : LEFT);
                xLastMousePosition = event.getX();
            });
        }

        enum Direction {
            LEFT,
            RIGHT
        }

        public Direction getLastDirection() {
            return direction;
        }
    }
    
}
```

End result (which works surprisingly well):

[image]

Comment: verified to work smoothly (and also slightly astonished, would have expected more trouble :) - could be a good starter to support in core, added a reference to this into https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213739

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I ought to vote for this feature on JBS but unfortunately didn't have permission to do it.

Comment: @PrimosK Better than voting for it, have you considered contributing a official fix? OpenJFX could probably use the help.  https://github.com/openjdk/jfx

Comment: @swpalmer I did.. But honestly I considered this solution more as a workaround (and not a proper fix) ... Anyway - I will be very happy if ideas used there will be used as a sprout for official fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible to work around.  You could start with something like this, though it is a very crude implementation, I'm sure in principle it can be refined to something reasonable:

```
    tableView.setOnMouseExited(me -> {
        if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) { // must be dragging
            Bounds tvBounds = tableView.getBoundsInLocal();
            double x = me.getX();
            if (x < tvBounds.getMinX()) {
                // Scroll to the left
                tableView.scrollToColumnIndex(0);
            } else if (x > tvBounds.getMaxX()) {
                // Scroll to the right
                tableView.scrollToColumnIndex(tableView.getColumns().size()-1);
            }
        }
    });
```

In a proper implementation you would likely have to sneak around the Node hierarchy and find the width of the table columns and determine what the next out-of-view column is so you can scroll to the exact right column. Remember when you did that so you can do it again if the user continues to drag outside the table, but not too fast.

EDIT: Based on your self-answer, here is my take on it.  I've compacted your code a bit and made it work on JavaFX 8.0:

```
static class TableHeaderScroller implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
    private TableView tv;
    private Pane header;
    private ScrollBar scrollBar;
    private double lastX;

    public static void install(TableView tv) {
        TableHeaderScroller ths = new TableHeaderScroller(tv);
        tv.skinProperty().addListener(ths::skinListener);
    }
    
    private TableHeaderScroller(TableView tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    private void skinListener(ObservableValue<? extends Skin<?>> observable, Skin<?> oldValue, Skin<?> newValue) {
        if (header != null) {
            header.removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, this);
        }
        header = (Pane) tv.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
        if (header != null) {
            tv.lookupAll(".scroll-bar").stream().map(ScrollBar.class::cast)
                    .filter(sb -> sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
                    .findFirst().ifPresent( sb -> {
                        TableHeaderScroller.this.scrollBar = sb;
                        header.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, TableHeaderScroller.this);
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        double x = event.getX();
        double sign = Math.signum(x - lastX);
        lastX = x;
        int dir = x < 0 ? -1 : x > header.getWidth() ? 1 : 0;
        if (dir != 0 && dir == sign) {
            if (dir < 0) {
                scrollBar.decrement();
            } else {
                scrollBar.increment();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an appreciation for encouragement (i.e. that it should be possible to do it using the current API) I am upvoting your answer but I can't accept it (as it's not complete/workable solution).